# Calculated Column next date

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to add a calculated field to a list that takes another field (which allows multi values) and picks up the next date.

See Below - Meeting ID is a lookup from another list and is populated via Power Automate.  I would like to populate the Next Meeting column with the next date (equal to or after today) so row 1 it would be Feb 24, for row 2 it would be Nov 23.

[image]

Any ideas of a formula that would handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint calculated column formulas.

SharePoint calculated column formulas does not support fetching values from:

- Lookup column - single selection
- Lookup column - multiple selection
- Choice column - multiple selection
- Person or Group column, etc.

So, you may need to do your calculations in Power automate flow and update column values when you populate Meeting ID from another list via Power Automate.